# Gradle output not formatted correctly in VS Code's bash terminal

Tags: bash, gradle, visual-studio-code

After a VS Code update a few weeks ago, Gradle's output started to display formatting character sequences like this:

[image: like this].

I'm running VS Code on Windows and my bash shell is the one installed with Git. When running Gradle in bash directly (outside of VS Code) the formatting is correct. How can I fix this in VS Code?

Answer (score 2):

How is VS Code invoking Gradle? Can you add the following to the Gradle command line that VS Code invokes?

```
--console=plain
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html

> Set to plain to generate plain text only. This option disables all color and other rich output in the console output. This is the default when Gradle is not attached to a terminal.

Comment: Thanks @lance-java. What you're suggesting is a good workaround. I would have liked to get the same behavior as I normally get but this is already much better. I was invoking just with gradle build --parallel in a bash terminal.